# How to make a pivot table with two sets of columns, each filtered differently

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

Suppose I have the following Excel data:

```
+------+-------+--------+
| Item | User  | Status |
+------+-------+--------+
| MTB  | Bob   | A      |
| QCD  | Bob   | A      |
| MTB  | Alice | B      |
| DFXR | Carol | A      |
| QCD  | Carol | B      |
| MTB  | Carol | B      |
| MTB  | Carol | A      |
| DFXR | Carol | B      |
+------+-------+--------+
```

I can pivot this data to get a count of items per user by item type, by putting `User` in the `Row Labels` box, `Item` in the `Column Labels` box, and `Count of Item` in the `Values` box.  This gives the following pivot:

```
+-------------+------+-----+-----+-------------+
| Row Labels  | DFXR | MTB | QCD | Grand Total |
+-------------+------+-----+-----+-------------+
| Bob         |      |   1 |   1 |           2 |
| Alice       |      |   1 |     |           1 |
| Carol       |    2 |   2 |   1 |           5 |
| Grand Total |    2 |   4 |   2 |           8 |
+-------------+------+-----+-----+-------------+
```

I want to create a pivot that will make two separate sets of `Count of Item` columns: one for **Status="A"** and the other for **Status="B"**.  It would look like this:

```
+-------------+----------+---------+---------+----------+---------+---------+-------------+
| Row Labels  | DFXR (A) | MTB (A) | QCD (A) | DFXR (B) | MTB (B) | QCD (B) | Grand Total |
+-------------+----------+---------+---------+----------+---------+---------+-------------+
| Bob         |          |       1 |       1 |          |         |         |           2 |
| Alice       |          |         |         |          |       1 |         |           1 |
| Carol       |        1 |       1 |         |        1 |       1 |       1 |           5 |
| Grand Total |        1 |       2 |       1 |        1 |       2 |       1 |           8 |
+-------------+----------+---------+---------+----------+---------+---------+-------------+
```

I'm flexible about how the column names would appear; the important thing is that the counts of `Item` get broken out into two sets based on `Status`.  How would I do this?  Can it be done with a pivot table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can easily be done with a Pivot Table.  All you need to do is set it up correctly:

1. Select User for your Row Labels
2. Select Item for your Values
3. Select Item again for your Column Labels
4. Select Status for your Column Labels also.

Here's what it will look like:

[image: Pivot with 2 categories]